# Unable to select id for animation in Kivy

Tags: android, python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I have a kv segment that is within my python code.

What I want to do is select this button and animate it. The animation itself is triggered by pressing `NoButton`. `NoButton` has a class of itself that is child to the root widget class. Unfortunately despite having been able to successfully reference id out of the kv code, i can't seem actually make use of it.

Pressing `NoButton` results in absolutely nothing. No errors, nothing. If I try to print the id what i get is the location of the button it references:

`<__main__.MainButton object at 0x7fd5db0d5590>`

Here is a snippet of the kv code:

```
<MainClass>:
<MainScreen>:
    id: main

    AnchorLayout:
        size: root.size
        anchor_x: 'center'
        anchor_y: 'center'
        padding: 0, 0, 0, 50
        MainButton:
            id: pics
            rgba: 1,5,1,1
            size_hint_x: None
            size_hint_y: None
            height: main.height / 1.5
            width: main.width / 1.5
```

and the python:

```
class MainScreen(Screen):
    pass

class MainButton(Button):
    pass

class NoButton(ButtonBehavior, Image, MainClass):
    def on_press(self):     
        anim = Animation(x=300, y=300)
        anim.start(MainButton())
        print(MainScreen().ids.pics)
```

You'll notice `anim.start` references the class rather than the id here. Unfortunately it produces the same result; nothing at all.

Creating `pics` as an object property and declaring that in kv fails to work too.

I really am completely clueless here. I've looked through the few questions that are slightly similar but there really isn't much when it comes to help/guides for in depth kivy development.

I'm using Python 3.5.3 and Kivy 1.9.2-dev0

Would appreciate any help/advice or pointers in the right direction :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating new objects instead of referencing the exiting ones

```
    anim.start(MainButton()) #new MainButton Object :(
    print(MainScreen().ids.pics) #also a new MainScreen object
```

I don't see in your code where is NoButton, but should get a hold on the MainScreen **instance** and from it extract the MainButton **instance**

```
main_button = main_screen.ids.pics
ani.start(main_button)
```

If you'll post a **runable example** I'll might be able to help you more, I guess...

Comment: main_screen isn't recognized :\

Comment: "*main_screen*" was just an example, without a working example it would be hard t guess the flow of your app...

Comment: thats all there is involving what i want to do. I just don't know how to successfully access id's from kv code